# Javascript onclick event to increase and decrease width

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

```js
function myFun(img) {
  img.style.width = "200px";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="images/img.jpg" id="test" width="100px" heigh="100px" onclick="myFun(this)">
</body>
```

So the code is when I click the image, the width increases by `100px`. What I wanted to achieve is that when I click the image again I wanted it to regain its actual width i.e `100px`. How to do so?...
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle the class when `onclick` event happens and when you click again the class will be removed so that you'll will your current size of `width`

### Example

```js
function myFun(img) {
  img.classList.toggle('thatClass');
}
```

```css
.thatClass {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="images/img.jpg" id="test" width="100px" heigh="100px" onclick="myFun(this)">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the state of the zoom - whether the user is currently zooming in or out, and depending on the bounds you have specified, change the zoom state.

```js
const $image = document.querySelector('#test');
const delta = 50;
let zoom = +1;
$image.onclick = function() {
  const height = $image.getBoundingClientRect().height; // or $image.height
  if (height >= 500) {
    zoom = -1;
  } else if (height <= 200) {
    zoom = +1;
  }
  $image.height += zoom * delta;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://media1.tenor.com/images/9f8deeccdee39a5ed36a0a7ecfa3a1a8/tenor.gif?itemid=10044706" height="200" id="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if/else statement in the function to test if the width is equal to "200px" then assign "100px" to the width otherwise asign "200px":

```js
function myFun(img) {
  if(img.style.width === "200px") {
    img.style.width = "100px";
  } else {
    img.style.width = "200px";
  }
}
```